# Serial port game controller (racing pedals)

Tags: drivers, serial-port, serial, game-controller

I have an old madCatz racing wheel for the playstation 2. The gas and brake pedals are connected to the wheel by a serial port. I just bought a usb racing wheel for the PC but it lacks pedals so I wanted to see if I could get these old madCatz working.
I just installed the serial port in my motherboard, but now I have a problem with software. Nothing will recognize the pedal. I was wondering if there are any programs or drivers out there that will allow me to set the pedals up to work.
Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: it's theoretically possible to do, but will take some work.  the pedals may not be using a standard pinout for the "serial connection".  best place to start is by digging up any specs/schematics you can for the specific model you have.  you may be looking at disassembling the pedals and/or writing your own drivers for them.

Answer (score 2):

It may use a DE-9 (no, it's not DB-9) connector, but that doesn't mean it's RS232 serial. In fact, it almost certainly isn't. If I'm correct on this, that means they won't work.

Comment: kind of what i meant by "non-standard pinout" in my earlier comment.  but you're not quite correct; it doesn't mean they won't work, it just means they won't work *without additional hardware* -- you'd need some sort of adapter to translate from RS232 to whatever the pedals use.

Comment: @~quack: The original question specifically stated "I was wondering if there are any programs or drivers out there that will allow me to set the pedals up to work." -- and if they use a nonstandard pinout as I suspect (and suggested), the answer *is* no. Building a custom interface was not asked, nor is it reasonably within the scope of the question asked.

Comment: On a more constructive note, it is likely the pedals are just [potentiometers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potentiometer) with (at least) two terminals connected to pins (possibly with one or more common pin). This can easily be verified by measuring resistance with a multimeter. If so, a simple passive device would make it interface with a standard [game port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_port). I believe more complex circuitry would be needed to connect it to something else.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since the question, but looking for a solution to this I found an Arduino based project for the Logitech G27 pedals that might be useful also in this case:

https://github.com/functionreturnfunction/G27_Pedals_and_Shifter

This is an Arduino project (code and wiring) that demonstrates it might be possible to intercept the data coming out from the pedals using a pass-through DB-9 interface with an Arduino board in the middle.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Welcome to Super User. Please read [How to Recommend Software](https://meta.superuser.com/a/5330/213131) then [edit] your answer to include at least the minimum required information (the items in **bold**). Posts without this information may be subject to deletion. Thanks for contributing.

Comment: I made edits to better explain what the link is about, anyway it's not possible to quote the code here because it's a full Arduino project with wiring and code.